# Homology of the Koszul Complex of a quotient ring: an explicit example.

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, binomial-ideals

Currently, I am learning about the Koszul complex as presented in the text "Binomial Ideals" by Herzog, Hibi and Ohsugi. To aid my understanding, I wanted to view an explicit computation of the homology of a Koszul complex, but I was unable to find anything helpful. If anybody could provide one I would be very grateful, otherwise I would just like to know where I'm going wrong in the example below.

Let $S = \mathbb{K}[x,y,z]$ be the standard graded polynomial ring in $3$ indeterminates over the field $\mathbb{K}$, $\mathbf{x} = x,y,z $ a regular sequence and $S/I$ a finitely generated graded $S$-module, where $I=(xy - z^2)$ is an ideal in $S$. The text states that the Koszul complex of $S/I$ with respect to $\mathbf{x}$ is given by $K(\mathbf{x};S/I) = K(\mathbf{x};S) \otimes_{S} S/I$, where $K(\mathbf{x};S)$ is the usual Koszul complex with respect to $\mathbf{x}$. So I would like to compute $H_{i}(\mathbf{x};S/I) $ for all $ i$.

If $F$ is a free $S$-module with basis $e_1,e_2,e_3$, then $K(\mathbf{x};S)$ can be written as follows. 
$$ 0 \longrightarrow \bigwedge\nolimits^3 F \xrightarrow{\begin{pmatrix}
z \\
-y \\
x
\end{pmatrix}} \bigwedge\nolimits^2 F \xrightarrow{\begin{pmatrix}
-y & -z & 0\\
x & 0 & -z\\
0 & x & y
\end{pmatrix}} F \xrightarrow{\begin{pmatrix} x & y & z \end{pmatrix}} S \xrightarrow{\partial_0} 0 $$
So now if we consider the complex $K(\mathbf{x};S/I)$, then the following homologies are easy to compute:

$H_{0}(K(\mathbf{x};S/I)) = \mathop{Ker}(\partial_0 \otimes_S 1)/\mathop{Im}(\partial_1 \otimes_S 1) \cong S/(x,y,z)$
$H_{2}(K(\mathbf{x};S/I)) = \mathop{Ker}(\partial_2 \otimes_S 1)/\mathop{Im}(\partial_3 \otimes_S 1) \cong 0$
$H_{3}(K(\mathbf{x};S/I)) = \mathop{Ker}(\partial_3 \otimes_S 1)/\mathop{Im}(\partial_4 \otimes_S 1) = 0$

But for $H_{1}(K(\mathbf{x};S/I))$ my result is not correct. It is clear that $\mathop{Ker}(\partial_1) = \mathop{Im}(\partial_2)$, so wouldn't this mean that $\mathop{Ker}(\partial_1 \otimes_{S} 1) = \mathop{Im}(\partial_2 \otimes_S 1)$?

A theorem in the above text states that the $\mathbb{K}$ dimension of these homologies is equal to the graded betti numbers of $S/I$, which I've already determined using Macaulay2 and by computing the minimal free $S$-resolution of $S/I$. From this I know the homology for $i=0,1$ should have $\mathbb{K}$-dimension $1$. Yet my computation of $H_{1}(K(\mathbf{x};S/I))$ does not agree with this.

Any help at all would be appreciated.

Comment: How did you show $ker (\partial_1 \otimes_S 1) = F \otimes S/I$?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. On second thought I might have been mistaken here, but I'm still not getting answers that correspond with Macaulay2. Since I've taken $F$ as a free $S-$Module, maybe I should have written $K_{0}(\mathbf{x},S) = S$ rather than $\mathbb{K}$. This would instead mean that $\partial_{1} = \begin{bmatrix} x & y & z \\ \end{bmatrix}$ and hence the Kernel of $\partial_{1}$ is the same as the Image of $\partial_{2}$. This just means that $H_{1}(K(\mathbf{x},S/I)) \cong 0$, which doesn't have $\mathbb{K}$-dimension 1.

Comment: Hi. The statement with the conclusion of "$\mathop{Ker}(\partial_1 \otimes_{S} 1) = \mathop{Im}(\partial_2 \otimes_S 1)$" is incorrect as tensoring by $S/I$ may not preserve left exactness. All the relations between $x,y,z$ belonged to the image of the koszul relations. Once you tensor with $S/I$, you created a new relation $(y,0,-z)$ which is not in the image of the Koszul relations. (The third row of $\partial_2$ does not contain $z$.)

Comment: This has answered my question, thank you so much.